# Google Sheets conditional formatting for multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like to set up conditional formatting in columns B:D such that blank cells in B:D are highlighted but only when the same row in A is NOT empty.

I think the custom formula should be something like this, but it's not working...

```
=and(not(isblank(A:A)),isblank($B:$D))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You got pretty close with your idea about ISBLANK.

Use this as the Custom formula applying to Columns B to D

```
=AND(not(isblank($A:$A)),isblank($B1:$D1))
```

The formula evaluates two ranges:
1) cell A = whether it is NOT empty
2) cell B or C or D = whether they are blank (that's the impact of the absolute column reference).
The criterion are joined with AND. So the net effect is as if to say:

If cell A is NOT empty, then apply the formatting to the cells in Column B, C, and D UNLESS the respective cell B, C or D is not empty in which case don't apply the formatting to that non-empty cell.

This is the screenshot of the indicative outcome.
[image]

**Credit:**
Absolute Vs Relatives references in critera: [Zig Mandel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value) and [tehhowch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534988/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-previous-cell)
Formatting Rule applying to a column: [Ed Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540556/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-on-a-column)